# Starting lighttpd with fastcgi and local unix-domain socket failed

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd, openbsd

/etc/lighttpd.conf:

```
...
server.modules = (
  "mod_fastcgi"
)
server.username  = "_lighttpd"
server.groupname = "_lighttpd"
fastcgi.server = (
   ".fcgi" =>
   ((
      "socket"   => "/tmp/a.out.socket",
      "bin-path" => "/tmp/a.out"
   ))
)
...
```

I run as root:

```
spawn-fcgi -s /tmp/a.out.socket -n -u _lighttpd -g _lighttpd -U _lighttpd -G _lighttpd -- /tmp/a.out
```

ps aux:

```
...
_lighttpd 28973 0.0 0.2 448 596 p1 I+ 2:33PM 0:00.01 /tmp/a.out
...
```

ls -ltr /tmp

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 _lighttpd  _lighttpd  6992 Jul 16 13:38 a.out
srwxr-xr-x  1 _lighttpd  _lighttpd     0 Jul 16 14:33 a.out.socket
```

Now I try to start lighttpd as root:

```
/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf
```

The logfile contains the following error:

```
2011-07-16 14:39:23: (log.c.166) server started
2011-07-16 14:39:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1367) --- fastcgi spawning local
    proc: /tmp/a.out
    port: 0
    socket /tmp/a.out.socket
    max-procs: 4
2011-07-16 14:39:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1391) --- fastcgi spawning
    port: 0
    socket /tmp/a.out.socket
    current: 0 / 4
2011-07-16 14:39:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.978) bind failed for: unix:/tmp/a.out.socket-0 No such file or directory
2011-07-16 14:39:23: (mod_fastcgi.c.1399) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.
2011-07-16 14:39:23: (server.c.938) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

What is wrong with my configuration? I run OpenBSD 4.9.

Many thanks in advance

Toru

Answer (score 2):

Lighttpd is chrooted. To solve the problem described above comment out "server.chroot" in /etc/lighttpd.conf.

Comment: +1 but whouldn't it be better to put the plugins on the chroot too?